# Introductory material for getting started with local and stochastic volatility modelling

Tags: volatility, stochastic-volatility, heston, local-volatility, sabr

Are you able to provide some suggestions for resources to get started with non-flat volatility modelling? The models I am interested in are the likes of CEV, Heston, SABR etc.

I have tried looking into Gatheral's *The volatility surface. A practitioner's guide* but it is a little too heavy so looking for something ideally more approachable.

I am looking for "first course in local and stochastic volatility modelling" really to get me started in this space. Thanks in advance for recommendations!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for a short introduction into various concepts used in volatility modeling without too much mathematical derivations (although written by a mathematician), I would recommend 'Smile pricing explained' by Peter Austing, Palgrave Macmillan (2014). It's a good first book to read and helpful in the future when you read more advanced books (like Gatheral).

Answer (score 6):

You may find [A Short Note on Volatility Models](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2272823) an interesting summary providing bird's-eye overview of general ideas in volatility modeling.

I would highly recommend [SABR and SABR LIBOR Market Models in Practice](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1057/9781137378644) as a great reference to SABR and SABR LMM accessible without prior knowledge of these models.